# onConfigurationChanged() is not called when Dark theme changes

Tags: android

Firstly, I have searched StackOverFlow for many hours before I post this question.
I tried to get onConfigurationChanged() called when user changes the theme in Setting but I've got no luck, event for other configs such as: Orientation, Screen size...
Please show me where I am doing wrong.

[image]

**Manifest file : use OnConfigChanges for handling config change event **

```
<activity
            android:name=".Notification.OnConfigChanges"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>
```

**OnConfigChanges class:**

```
public class OnConfigChanges extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_on_config_changes);
        Log.d("onConfig","Yes");
        Toast.makeText(this,"onConfig",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        Log.d("onConfig","Yes");
        Toast.makeText(this,"onConfig",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

Comment: Post your theme changing code, please.

Comment: I only check for Log and Toast to see if the method is called or not.

Comment: Changing the dark mode configuration in Android Settings does not affect your app without doing anything on your side, are you trying to do so?

Comment: I will set the text color of notification to WHITE if the Dark Mode is enabled.